# my links using html aren't working?

Tags: html

So I'm working on a website

```
<img src="Images/PaintEverythingPreview.png" herf="Pages/PaintEverything.html">
<p> - <a herf="Pages/PaintEverything.html">
Paint Everything
</a> - </p>
```

and the code here isn't working, none of the links work! I've coded a little program on my website, and this is supposed to take you to it, but it's not working, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use href instead of herf.

```
<a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html">Paint Everything</a>
```

[HTML Tags](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/bl_index.htm)

Comment: Just to throw in something else.  Because careful of all those capitol letters.  Your server may be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to include a link in your HTML is to use the `href` element (you mis-spelt it as `herf`.

Secondly, you cannot use `href` inside an `img` tag as it's not valid HTML. Instead, you should nest the `img` tag inside the link.

Update your code to this:

```
<a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html">
<img src="Images/PaintEverythingPreview.png">
</a>

<p>
<a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html">Paint Everything</a>
</p>
```

To validate (check) your HTML in the future, try the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to remove href from the image tag, since you cannot put a href in an `<img>` tag.
Secondly you need to check if the path/link to which you want to redirect to, is correct or not.

I have updated your code and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
<img src="Images/PaintEverythingPreview.png"><p> - <a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html">Paint Everything</a> - </p>
```

Comment: did you try this? this has the same issue as the OP - namely, there is a typo in the anchor tag's `href` attribute

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I had just copied it without changing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Change `herf` to `href` and enclose the `img` in `<a>` tags to make the image a clickable link.

```
<a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html"><img src="Images/PaintEverythingPreview.png"></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

error writing the attribute href.

```
    <a href="Pages/PaintEverything.html"> Paint Everything </a>
```

error in attribute href in img tag (not exists):

```
<img src="Images/PaintEverythingPreview.png" herf="Pages/PaintEverything.html">
```

html tag reference: [HTML tags list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp)

Comment: You cannot use the `href` tag in an `img` element